# raspberry pi model b+ Not booting

Tags: boot, hdmi, display, boot-issues, software-installation

I recently bought a raspberry pi 3 b+ from amazon and when I got it delivered the package was already opened, so I just want to check if my raspberry is working or not so I formatted a compatible sd card and installed noobs on it and mounted it on the pi.

It shows a red light and a green light which keeps blinking which means it reads from sd-card. My problem is that when I connect to tv using hdmi there isn't any signal.

So then I tried to install raspbian by etcher. The pi doesn't even read from sd card and by the way all the OS which I've installed are the updated versions from official website.

So do you think the prob is the device?

Comment: The raspberrypi.org forum has a comprehensive boot problems sticky post.  I suggest you look through that and then update your question.  A lot of problems are down to insufficient power supply.